# JAX-RS 2.1.1 Response building throwing error

Tags: java, maven, jax-rs

Whether I do

```
return Response.ok().build();
```

or

```
return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity(msg).build();
```

its throwing me error:

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.Response$ResponseBuilder.status(ILjava/lang/String;)Ljavax/ws/rs/core/Response$ResponseBuilder;

    at javax.ws.rs.core.Response$ResponseBuilder.status(Response.java:897)
    at javax.ws.rs.core.Response.status(Response.java:568)
    at javax.ws.rs.core.Response.status(Response.java:579)
```

[image]

Jar is `javax.ws.rs-api-2.1.1.jar`. I am confused. In the `mvn dependency:tree` log, I see only three entries of `javax.ws.rs` with above version. I had earlier excluded this artifact from some other dependencies as they were brining `2.0`. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like you are missing a runtime/implementation of that API.
You need a server like Glassfish, Tomcat that implements that API in order to run the code.

Comment: Ok, you made sense, let me revisit the exclusions.